# How to rename buildNumber property name in buildnumber-maven-plugin

Tags: maven, pom.xml, osgi-bundle, buildnumber-maven-plugin

How to rename buildNumber property name in buildnumber-maven-plugin

as mentioned in: 
http://mojo.codehaus.org/buildnumber-maven-plugin/create-mojo.html#buildNumberPropertyName

buildNumberPropertyName:

You can rename the buildNumber property name to another property name if desired.
Type: java.lang.String
Since: 1.0-beta-1
Required: No
User Property: maven.buildNumber.buildNumberPropertyName
Default: buildNumber

Answer (score 3):

Just as you quote. You have to use property `buildNumberPropertyName`. For ex:

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
<artifactId>buildnumber-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.3</version>
<inherited>true</inherited>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <id>generate-timestamp</id>
        <phase>validate</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>create</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <format>{0,date,yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z}</format>
            <items>
                <item>timestamp</item>
            </items>
            <buildNumberPropertyName>buildDateTime</buildNumberPropertyName>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
</executions>
```

Using above configuration, build time will be visible as `${buildDateTime}` maven property. Don't worry if your IDE will complaining about that it doesn't see creation of this property.

You can use default name as well: `${buildNumber}`

Answer (score 0):

in the configuration of maven buildnumber plugin, specify the optional attribute : “buildNumberPropertyName” with the custom name.